Angular material select not disabled on page load
I am trying to display a parent and child select lists in Angular 18 and Angular material 18.
I would like the initial parent to have "Show all" selected which then disables the child select list. Should the parent value be changed - the child select list should become enabled. It seems that when using the [disabled] input on the child - it isn't triggered on load but does work if "Show all" is subsequently selected after making changes.
Any ideas - I have made this stackblitz which shows the problem.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/4wkc6t

You have a warning in the browser console: "It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors."

The attribute disabled is not respected in reactive forms. The same is reported elsewhere in SO and in Github issues. Here and Here.
Instead, do it in the code, as you can surely figure out:
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
  <h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="selectedItem" (selectionChange)="foodSelectionChange($event)">
      <mat-option value="Show all">Show all</mat-option>
      @for (food of foods; track food) {
      <mat-option [value]="food">{{food}}</mat-option>
      }
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Sub type</mat-label>
    <mat-select
      formControlName="subFood"
      [disabled]="testForm.controls['selectedItem'].value === 'Show all'"
    >
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

And in the class:
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  private fb = inject(FormBuilder);

  testForm = this.fb.group({
    selectedItem: [''],
    subFood: [''],
  });

  foods: string[] = ['Vegetables', 'Meat', 'Poultry', 'Fish'];

  constructor() {
    this.testForm.controls['selectedItem'].setValue('Show all');
    this.configureSubFoodsSelect();
  }

  private configureSubFoodsSelect() {
    if (this.testForm.controls['selectedItem'].value === 'Show all') {
      this.testForm.controls['subFood'].disable();
    } else {
      this.testForm.controls['subFood'].enable();
    }
  }

  foodSelectionChange(event: MatSelectChange) {
    this.configureSubFoodsSelect();
  }
}

